# svg markers shown stripped

Tags: svg

The following attempt to use SVG marker does not work. the marker appears to be on the background under a strip. I cannot find any reason why its rendering does not seem to bringing it up and sized properly.

```
<svg id="svg-main" height="1800" width="1600">
<defs>
    <marker id="connection_marker_circle_start" markerWidth="10" markerHeight ="10" refX="5" refY="5" orient="auto">
        <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" style="fill: rgb(48, 48, 48);"></circle>
    </marker>
    <marker id="connection_marker_basic_end" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refX="2" refY="6" orient="auto"><path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill: rgb(48, 48, 48);"></path></marker>
</defs>
<line x1="186" x2="478" y1="123" y2="617" marker-start="url(#connection_marker_circle_start)" marker-end="url(#connection_marker_basic_end)" style="stroke: rgb(128, 128, 128); stroke-width: 2px"></line>
</svg>
```

JSFiddle project:

http://jsfiddle.net/guidoextras/L62j7r6x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple typo.  markerHight should be markerHeight.